# 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'payment_status'

Tags: django, orm

I am creating an app in which I want to query all the members and their status. but I am getting above error.
these are my both models.

```
class Member(models.Model ):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users,verbose_name='User Id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    com = models.ForeignKey(Committee, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Committee Name')

class PaymentDetail(models.Model):
    mem = models.ForeignKey(Member,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='payment_details', verbose_name='Memeber Phone no')
    com = models.ForeignKey(Committee, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='committee_details',verbose_name='Committee Name')
    payment_month = models.DateField(default=datetime.now())
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=PAYMENT_DETAILS_CHOICES, default="1")
```

First I am getting all the members by (members.objects.all() then looping over like this
for member in members:
member.payment_details.payment_status

but I am getting this error related manager has no attribute.

actually I can get data from PaymentDetail.objects.all() but it will only show data from PaymentDetail table. I want all the members and next to them their status from PaymentDetail table

Comment: Loop over `member.payment_details.all()` for each member

Comment: Ok yes I am getting the result but I have 10 members in Member table. where three of them only have payment_status(3 member's data are in PaymentDetail) so I am getting three members in output. What I want is to have all those 10 Members with their payment_status ( obviously 7 of them will be empty).  because I have to render in my template.

Answer (score 1):

You have ForeingKey relation, this is relation one to many, if you wanna access to `payment_details` you have to ask for all related objects by `payment_details.all()`.

Consider using one to one relation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)
, after change to one to one relation this `member.payment_details.payment_status` will be work.